# the use statement with non-compound name 'Auth' has no effect laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am unable to use Auth in my seeder class. I need to get tenant_id variable for my saas application. Here's my seeder class.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\AccountType;
use Auth;

class AccountTypeTableSeeder extends Seeder{

public function run()
{

    $accountType = new AccountType;
    $accountType->name = 'Travel Agent';
    $accountType->description = 'It is the description of the Travel Agent, so you write in detaisl about the account type.';
    $accountType->tenant_id = Auth::user()->tenant_id;
    $accountType->save();


}
```

}

And i called

```
$this->call(AccountTypeTableSeeder::class);
```

Comment: try `auth()->user()->tenant_id`, Report back .

Comment: same error, "the use statement with non-compound name 'Auth' has no effect laravel".

Comment: please post full file

Comment: Docs say $user = Auth::user(); // Get the currently authenticated user. But since you are in the seeder you dont have an authenticated user?

Comment: I guess so, but i want to call my seeder class programatically using         Artisan::call('db:seed'); but am unable to get the current authenticated user tenant_id using Auth facade.

Comment: i tried to post the whole seeder class above by updating

Answer (score 1):

In the top of your file put:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Comment: i did, and i also tried, use Auth; Both giving the same error.

Comment: This was what worked for me, I was trying to use `Auth::check()` in my routes file when not logged in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As i needed the tenand_id, i did it with the last inserted id of the user and got the tenant_id when seeding programmatically.

```
Artisan::call('db:seed');
```

i used

```
User::latest()->first()->tenant_id;
```